# Order by in Pivot Column not in Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-order-by

Table-A

| Productid | Brandname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C Brand |
| 2 | K Brand |
| 3 | A Brand |

Table-B

| Productid | Rate | Slab |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | 1 |
| 3 | 30 | 1 |
| 1 | 12 | 2 |
| 2 | 22 | 2 |
| 3 | 32 | 2 |

Dynamic Pivot Query:-

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Brandname) from [Table-A] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT Slab,' + @cols + '
             from 
             (
                select a.BrandName, b.Rate,b.Slab from [Table-A] a inner join [Table-B] b on a.productid=b.productid 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Rate)
                for Brandname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Result:-

| Slab | A Brand | C Brand | K Brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 32 | 12 | 22 |

But I need to order Brandname Column using productid

Expected Result:-

| Slab | C Brand | K Brand | A Brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2 | 12 | 22 | 32 |

Answer (score 1):

While preparing column list  for dynamic pivot use **order by productid** and remove distinct your problem will be solved.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table [Table-A](Productid   int,Brandname varchar(10));
 insert into [Table-A] values(1 ,'C Brand');
 insert into [Table-A] values(2 ,'K Brand');
 insert into [Table-A] values(3 ,'A Brand');
 
 create table [Table-B] (Productid  int, Rate   int , Slab int)
 insert into [Table-B] values(1 ,10 ,1);
 insert into [Table-B] values(2 ,20 ,1);
 insert into [Table-B] values(3 ,30 ,1);
 insert into [Table-B] values(1 ,12 ,2);
 insert into [Table-B] values(2 ,22 ,2);
 insert into [Table-B] values(3 ,32,2);
```

Query:

```
     DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Brandname) from [Table-A] order by productid FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
 
    
 set @query = 'SELECT Slab,' + @cols + '
              from 
              (
                 select a.BrandName, b.Rate,b.Slab from [Table-A] a inner join [Table-B] b on a.productid=b.productid 
             ) x
             pivot 
             (
                 max(Rate)
                 for Brandname in (' + @cols + ')
             ) p '
 
 execute(@query)
```

Output:

| Slab | C Brand | K Brand | A Brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2 | 12 | 22 | 32 |

If you are using SQL Server 2017 or above string_agg() will be smarter and faster option.

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
 select distinct @cols=STRING_AGG(quotename(brandname),',')  from [Table-A] 
 
     set @query = 'SELECT Slab,' + @cols + '
                  from 
                  (
                     select a.BrandName, b.Rate,b.Slab from [Table-A] a inner join [Table-B] b on a.productid=b.productid 
                 ) x
                 pivot 
                 (
                     max(Rate)
                     for Brandname in (' + @cols + ')
                 ) p '
     
     execute(@query)
```

Output:

| Slab | C Brand | K Brand | A Brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2 | 12 | 22 | 32 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=88a39a19ad478c89ff6c8c37d6de8ad0)*

Comment: @Sathesh Kumar Please let me know if you are facing any more difficulties with this query.

Comment: Please accept this answer by clicking green check if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You want the columns to be in a particular order.  You don't seem to need the `SELECT DISTINCT` in the subquery, based on your data.  But if you do, you can use aggregation instead:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Brandname) 
                      FROM [Table-A]
                      GROUP BY BrandName
                      ORDER BY MIN(ProductId)
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                            ), 1, 1, '')
```

However, without aggregation:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Brandname) 
                      FROM [Table-A]
                      ORDER BY ProductId
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                            ), 1, 1, '');
```

Once `@cols` is in the right order, the rest of the query should fall into place.